# Inline JavaScript with RedDot CMS version 9

Tags: javascript, cms

I can not put in inline JavaScript in text area in reddot opentext cms version 9.  when saving code it automatically strips it out.  Does anyone know any hack or work around to solve this problem.  I do not want this fix to be done globally because we have other users in the cms which are not admins i want this done on a single or a certain page only.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I wouldn't recommend puttin any inline javascript into a page.
If you have to do it, create a new template with a text element which is set to ASCII only and add your JS in this text element. 
You can connect the instance to a container within the page any run your Javascript inline.